# Where can we download numbers?

Tags: script

We need a file that has the numbers in it:

```
0000000000..1000000000
```

and

```
0..1000000000
```

where can we download these kind of lists?

Example #1:

```
000000001
000000002
...
099999999
100000000
```

Example #2: 
1
2
...
999999999
1000000000

If I search for torrent sites or just Google I can only find files that holds ~8 digits, but we need 10.

We tried to generate these files:

```
var=0; while true; do var=$((var+1)); echo $var >> sorted-generated-only-numbers-length-from-1-to-10-chars-zero-at-start-too.txt; done
```

but it will take ages to generate the file, even with a bigger machine. Seriously..

UPDATE: We tried to use: 
    var=0; var2=100000; while true; do tmpbuffer100k=$(seq $var $var2; var=$((var+100000)); var2=$((var2+100000))); echo "$tmpbuffer100k" >> output.txt; done

to avoid writing to the disk, rather we put ex.: 100 000 numbers in a variable, then write it to a disk - to make it faster, but it isn't working yet. It keeps writing only the first range, 1..100000

Comment: Your current approach opens the file for each line written. That's incredibly inefficient. You also don't ever stop...?

Comment: I will CTRL+C it when it finishes, but if I would put an "if reached enough exit 0" It would be slower. So you are suggesting to put the numbers in a variable then when reached a very high number, output it to a file?

Comment: Sounds totally like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/267029), what do you need these for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here’s an efficient pure Bash solution:

```
function print_numbers {
  current_num=$1
  target_num=$2
  target_num_length=${#target_num}

  while [ $current_num -le $target_num ]; do
    printf "%0${target_num_length}d\n" $current_num
    # or just "echo $current_num" if padding is not required
    current_num=$((current_num + 1))
  done
}

print_numbers 0 10 > target_file
```

Because it uses only Bash built-ins, no additional processes are created. It opens the file `target_file` *once* and redirects all output from the function to that file.

The function aborts automatically when reaching the target value.

Of course, compared to a native tool like `seq`, it’s still incredibly slow:

```
db-nb-13:~ fuzzy$ time print_numbers 0 100000 > /dev/null

real    0m2.909s
user    0m2.761s
sys 0m0.139s
db-nb-13:~ fuzzy$ time print_numbers 0 1000000 > /dev/null

real    0m30.974s
user    0m29.074s
sys 0m1.651s

db-nb-13:~ fuzzy$ time seq -w 0 1000000 > /dev/null

real    0m0.370s
user    0m0.363s
sys 0m0.003s
```

## Warning

The resulting files will be *very* large. A file containing 0..1000000000, padded with zeroes, will have

```
1 000 000 000 * (10 (bytes for 10 digits – ASCII!) + 1 (newline)) = 11 000 000 000 bytes
```

That’s **10.24 GiB**! You *really* should reconsider your approach to whatever problem you’re trying to solve.

Comment: +1 for the warning alone. Such a weird requirement is a red flag. 10 GB of sequential numbers is probably not *the* solution, but a part of a broken solution to entirely different problem.

Answer (score 4):

Let's check first the solution for **example 2:**

On Linux you have `seq`, for example :

```
seq 099999990 100000000
```

will print this list:

```
99999990
99999991
99999992
99999993
99999994
99999995
99999996
99999997
99999998
99999999
100000000
```

Direct the output into a file:

```
seq 1 100000000 > the_file.txt
```

---

Now that you understand how `seq` works let's go back to **example 1**:

If you add to `seq` the flag `-f` you can add a padding to the generated sequence, for example:

```
seq -f "%05g" 1 10
```

Will add a padding to each number to format as 5 digit long:

```
00001
00002
00003
00004
00005
00006
00007
00008
00009
00010
```

For your specific case you will need to use `-f "%010g"` to achieve the 10 digit long numbers.

Comment: The `-w` flag is a faster way to get padding up to the amount of digits in the upper limit.